# FlatList show according to TextInput handle

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have Dynamic form in which user can add form and remove form when user start typing on first form TextInput it will give suggestion as per input. Now the problem is when user start typing on first TextInput field it will get suggestion but when user add another form by clicking on addForm Button and when user start typing on new form it will get suggestion but on same time in the first form it also start giving suggestion and same if there is three form it will start giving suggestion for all three form if user start typing in one form.I want to say that If user type any of form it will give suggestion on all form.

I want like if user is on first form then it will give suggestion only for first form not for second form as well. if user is on second form it will only get suggestion on second form not on first as well.

[image: giving suggestion for both form even I'm typing on second form]

**You can see in above picture it is giving suggestion for both form even if I'm typing on second form**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { 
    View,
    TextInput,
    ScrollView,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    StyleSheet,
    Picker,
    ListView,
    FlatList
  } from 'react-native'
 import { getStockItems } from "../../actions/getIndentsAction";

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {  CardSection, Text, Button, Block, Input } from '../../components';
import { theme } from '../../constants';
import { MaterialIcons,AntDesign,Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { CardItem,Content, ListItem,Icon,Card, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';



class IndentForm extends PureComponent {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const { params = {} } = navigation.state;    
        return {
          headerRight: (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => params.handleSave()}>
                <AntDesign

                    name='plus'
                    style={{ paddingRight:10}}
                    size={25}
                    color='white'
                />

              </TouchableOpacity>

          )
        };
    };


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         companyName:'',
         formFields:[{
            Item_Description:'',
            Quantity:'',
         }],
         searchedForm:[]
        };
      }


      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.navigation.setParams({ handleSave: this.addInput});
        this.props.getStockItems()
      }


      //add dynamic form
      addInput = () => {
        const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
        const allFormFieldsAfterAddingNew = [...existingFormFields, {Item_Description: '', Quantity:''}]
        this.setState({formFields: allFormFieldsAfterAddingNew})
      }

      //remove dynamic form
      removeInput = index => () => {
        this.setState({
            formFields: this.state.formFields.filter((s, sidx) => index !== sidx)
        });
      };


      //on Item Descriptionchange
      onItemDescriptionChange = (text, index) => {
        const { stocks } = this.props.indent;

        const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
        let targetField = {...existingFormFields[index]}
        targetField.Item_Description = text
        existingFormFields[index] = targetField

        var searchedForm = stocks.filter(function(stock) {
          return stock.Item.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
        this.setState({searchedForm: searchedForm , formFields: existingFormFields})

      }


      //on Quantity change
      onQuantityChange = (text, index) => {
        const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
        let targetField = {...existingFormFields[index]}
        targetField.Quantity = text
        existingFormFields[index] = targetField

        this.setState({formFields: existingFormFields})
      }



    itemSelect = (item,index) => {
      const existingFormFields = this.state.formFields.map(fields => ({...fields}))
      let targetField = {...existingFormFields[index]}
      targetField.Item_Description = item.Item
      existingFormFields[index] = targetField

      this.setState({searchedForm:[], formFields:existingFormFields})

      console.log("hello" + " " + item.Item + " " + index);

    }


      onsubmit = () => {
          const data = {
              companyName:this.state.companyName,
              formFields:this.state.formFields
          }
        console.log(data)      
    }



    render() {
        const { stocks } = this.props.indent;


        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1, justifyContent:"center"}} behavior="padding">

                <ScrollView 
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                >

                        <Block  padding={[5]}>
                            <Card>
                                <Picker
                                    style={{flex:1}}
                                    selectedValue={this.state.companyName}   
                                    onValueChange={(companyName)=>this.setState({companyName:companyName})} 
                                >
                                   <Picker.Item label='developer' value="0" />
                                   <Picker.Item label="Developer" value="Developer" />
                                    <Picker.Item label="Junior Develope" value="Junior Develope" />
                                </Picker>

                            </Card>

                            {
                                this.state.formFields.map((field, index) => {
                                    return(
                                        <Card key={index} >
                                            <CardItem bordered>
                                                <Left>
                                                        <Text bold>Items no : {index + 1}</Text>
                                                </Left>
                                                <Right>
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                                        onPress={this.removeInput(index)}
                                                    >
                                                    <Entypo
                                                        name="cross"
                                                        size={20}
                                                        color='#E46932'
                                                    />
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>

                                                </Right>
                                            </CardItem>

                                            <Block padding={[0, theme.sizes.base]}>

                                                    <Block>

                                                    <Input 
                                                        label="description"
                                                        style={[styles.input]}
                                                        value={field.Item_Description}   
                                                        onChangeText={(text)=> this.onItemDescriptionChange(text, index)}
                                                    /> 



                                                      <FlatList
                                                            data={this.state.searchedForm}
                                                            keyExtractor={(ItemId,index) => index.toString()}
                                                            renderItem={({item,index})=>(
                                                              <ListItem
                                                                button={true}
                                                                key={index}
                                                                onPress={()=>this.itemSelect(item,index)}
                                                              >

                                                                <Text bold>{item.Item}</Text>
                                                              </ListItem>

                                                            )} 
                                                          />
                                                    </Block>





                                                    <Input 
                                                        label="Quantity"
                                                        style={[styles.input]}
                                                        value={field.Quantity}   
                                                        onChangeText={(text)=> this.onQuantityChange(text, index)}
                                                    />

                                            </Block>


                                        </Card>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                            <Block padding={[0, theme.sizes.base * 1.5]}>


                                <Button
                                    style={styles.submitInput}
                                    onPress={this.onsubmit}>
                                    <Text bold white center>Submit</Text>
                                </Button>
                            </Block>

                        </Block>


                </ScrollView>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )
    }
}


IndentForm.propTypes = {
    getStockItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    indent: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    indent: state.indent,
    errors:state.errors
  });

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    { 
        getStockItems,
    }
  )(IndentForm);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        borderRadius: 0,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderBottomColor: theme.colors.gray2,
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        marginLeft:5
    },
    submitInput:{
        backgroundColor:"#2ecc71"
    },
    addInput:{
        backgroundColor:"white"
    },
    addButton:{
        alignItems:"flex-end",
        position:"absolute",
        right:20,
        bottom:20,
      },
      searchBarContainerStyle: {
        marginBottom: 10,
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 40,
        shadowOpacity: 1.0,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 1,
          height: 1
        },
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        shadowColor: "#d3d3d3",
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 3,
        marginLeft: 10,
        marginRight: 10
      },

      selectLabelTextStyle: {
        color: "#000",
        textAlign: "left",
        width: "99%",
        padding: 10,
        flexDirection: "row"
      },
      placeHolderTextStyle: {
        color: "#D3D3D3",
        padding: 10,
        textAlign: "left",
        width: "99%",
        flexDirection: "row"
      },
      dropDownImageStyle: {
        marginLeft: 10,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        alignSelf: "center"
      },

      pickerStyle: {
        marginLeft: 18,
        elevation:3,
        paddingRight: 25,
        marginRight: 10,
        marginBottom: 2,
        shadowOpacity: 1.0,
        shadowOffset: {
          width: 1,
          height: 1
        },
        borderWidth:1,
        shadowRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
        shadowColor: "#d3d3d3",
        borderRadius: 5,
        flexDirection: "row"
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do **addInput**, it adds new FlatList for each input. but, data of FlatList is managed by single state which is **this.state.searchedForm**.

So whenever **onItemDescriptionChange** gets called, it updates the **searchedForm** state and all the FlatList reflects that change.

To resolve this, either you'll have to keep the FlatList data inside **formFields** state as one key or you can manage different state for each input.